# how to create a .launch file with a node developed with ROSJava

Tags: roslaunch, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a .launch file to use the command:

```
roslaunch robot.launch
```

But, I don't know how to translate the following shell call into a .launchfile:

```
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py bumperCar 
org.lejos.ros.nodes.bumpercar.BumperCarControl __name:=BumperCarControl
```

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12549/how-to-create-a-.launch-file-with-a-node-developed-with-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to add an extra `args=""` parameter to your `<node>` tag. For more information, take a look at the [XML docs for `<node>`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node)

**EDIT**: Try something like:

`<node pkg="rosjava_bootstrap" type="run.py" args="bumperCar org.lejos.ros.nodes.bumpercar.BumperCarControl" name="BumperCarControl" />`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2012-12-17**:
I get the message "Can't locate 'run.py' in 'rosjava_bootstrap' ".  I can launch it fine when I use ./build/install/bin/test theTest